# Generate email body from user input, send email from controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, system.net.mail

Basically I have an html form that I want to take the user input from, generate an email body with it, and send the email. I've never programmed anything like this before, so I've spent the past few days researching different ways to send emails from a website, but none of the examples I've found relate to my exact situation. Fooling around with different methods I have found hasn't proven fruitful either.

As it stands right now, I have a model that declares each string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace myWebsite.Models
{
    public class ServiceRequest
    {
        [Key]
        public int serviceRequestID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string serviceRequestName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string serviceRequestEmail { get; set; }
        public string serviceRequestCompany { get; set; }
        public string serviceRequestAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string serviceType { get; set; }
        public string serviceRequestCity { get; set; }
        public string serviceRequestState { get; set; }
        public string serviceRequestZip { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string serviceRequestNumber { get; set; }
        public string serviceRequestComments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then in the view I've created the form using @html helpers to link the strings from my model to the user input fields:

```
@model myWebsite.ServiceRequest

@using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "ServiceRequestsController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="servicesReq">
        <div class="serviceReqForm">
            <div class="col-left">
                <label>
                    <span class="required">* </span><span>Name:</span><br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.serviceRequestName)
                </label><br />
                        <label>
                            <span class="required">* </span><span>Email:</span><br />
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.serviceRequestEmail)
                        </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span>Company:</span><br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.serviceRequestCompany)
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span>Address:</span><br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.serviceRequestAddress)
                </label><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="serviceTypeGrid">
                <span class="required">* </span><span>Please choose what type of servicing you require:</span><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-left2">
                <label class="serviceType">
                    @Html.RadioButton("serviceType", "Electrical") Electrical<br/>
                    @Html.RadioButton("serviceType", "Lighting") Lighting<br />
                    @Html.RadioButton("serviceType", "Energy") Energy<br />
                    @Html.RadioButton("serviceType", "Multiple") Multiple
                </label><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-right">
                <label>
                    <span>City:</span><br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.serviceRequestCity)
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span>State:</span><br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.serviceRequestState)
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span>Zip Code:</span><br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.serviceRequestZip)
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span class="required">* </span><span>Phone Number:</span><br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.serviceRequestNumber)
                </label><br />
            </div>
            <label class="commentText">
                <span>Comments:</span><br />
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.serviceRequestComments, new { @class = "servReqComment" })
            </label>
            <div class="formSubmitButton">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

And finally my controller logic - which is where I'm pretty much completely lost:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using myWebsite.Models;

namespace myWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class ServiceRequestsController : Controller
    {
        private CuttingEdgeWebsite2_0Context db = new CuttingEdgeWebsite2_0Context();

        // GET: ServiceRequests
        public ActionResult ServiceRequest()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

As I said before, I've looked up a few different ways but they all involved hard-coding an email body. Everything I've tried with my limited knowledge, I can't get to generate the body from user input on my form. While I have sort of kind of an idea on how to actually send the mail, any in-depth clarification of that process would also be very very helpful. If there's any information I haven't provided here that you might find useful, please let me know.

Comment: You've got multiple things in here: building up a mail body, creating and sending a mail message, and doing this in your controller. I think you should break it down and look at one piece at a time. First thing I would do is determine what format you want your email to take (html formatted or not, hardcoded text, etc). Ultimately, you will have to create a string that contains the body of the email so you should work on a method that accepts your incoming object and returns the string object for the email body.

Answer (score 0):

This should get your started. There are (at minimum) four properties to sending an email programtically. These are fromaddres, toaddress, subject, and body.

In your form you are going to want to take advantage of the validationsummary. This provides validation feedback to the user. Just insert

`@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

right after your BeginForm line

Based on your code, this kind of thing would work.
In your controller, you need a method to handle the post of your form data and some method to send the email (should be in a seperate method for good design).

```
[HttpPost]    
public async Task Email(ServiceRequest servicerequest)
{
    try
    {
        string from = "youremailadress@gmail.com"
        string to = servicerequest.serviceRequestEmail;
        string subject = servicerequest.serviceType;
        //it's up to you what you want to put in the body
        string body = String.Format("city:{0}\n\nComments:{1}\n\n
        PhoneNumber\n\n",serviceRequest.serviceRequestCity, 
        serviceRequest.serviceRequestComments, serviceRequest.serviceRequestNumber);
        string email = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email"];
        string password = 
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailpassword"];
        string server = 
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailserver"];
        string emailport = 
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailport"];
        int port = Int32.Parse(emailport);
        var client = new SmtpClient(server, port)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        await client.SendMailAsync("from", to, subject, body);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error occured at {0}. Full stack trace of error {1}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString(),e.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you make an empty catch block?

Comment: @Mason because catching exceptions isnt relevant to the question.

Comment: If it’s not relevant, why did you put a try/catch?

Comment: Why? Why put a try catch if you’re not going to do anything? Especially an empty try catch. Your code is going to be seen by new coders. Teach them right, don’t litter try catches in the code that don’t do anything. Get people started on good habits early.

Comment: Ok, fixed. I would agree an empty try...catch is generally neglecting an error condition that should be handled. But not always. In certain circumstances, like when dealing with connections to remote servers, like tcp/ip remoting, the error condition that arises from low level communication is irrelevant, and a retry operation is needed regardless of the cause. anyways, updated